# Open Java program from SSH into VNC display

Tags: ssh, java, vnc, lxde

If I have an Ubuntu 12.04 system that has LXDE and TightVNCserver installed and run a session on port `:1` (not tunneled through SSH) and an active SSH connection, then how can I use SSH to start a program that needs an active display to use the tightVNC session available?

I wanted to use SSH to start a java file that normally starts fine when started inside of the vnc session, but i get an error:

```
xxx@yyy:~# java zzz
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
Caused by: java.awt.HeadlessException:
No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an operation which requires it.
        at sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenSize(HeadlessToolkit.java:282)
        at zzz.<clinit>(zzz.java:35)
```

To rephrase it: I want to start a program and let it use the open VNC session's window without using the VNC client viewer session to start it, can this be done?

(I think any program that needs a display would react that way, so i think it's not so much of a java question but an ssh/vnc one)

Comment: I read a bit about x11 forwarding.  "xvfb provides a null x server (i.e. one without a real display) for applications to run on when you are not sshed in to the target machine." Why would I need this if the target machine already has a tightvncserver session available? Im still beginning to wrap my head around it... What i seem to have to do is using ssh x11 forwarding to open the java on my machine, then move it to the :1 session of the target machine?

Comment: The solution muru provided was what i wanted to do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `DISPLAY` variable to the X server of the VNC session:

```
DISPLAY=:1 java xxx
```

Answer (score 2):

You will need to enable X11 forwarding, this will forward it to your own X11 server (so you need a running X11 server on the client you're SSHing from).

This can be done by adding `-X` to your SSH command.
Example: `ssh -X user@server`

Then make sure that the $DISPLAY variable is set to the correct display. Check this with `echo $DISPLAY`

If what you're trying to achieve, is accessing an open Window on your X11 server through SSH, I'll suggest taking a look at this: http://www.wensley.org.uk/x

It explains how to achieve behaviour similiar to 'screen', but with X11 applications.

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of things you can do here I guess, one way is to use `ssh -X` command.

However, I like the approach of running a VNC server (like tightvnc) on you host that you're trying to connect to. Then you can `ssh` to that host and use a vnc viewer for the display if you need it. On your `ssh` terminal, connect to your host vnc and forward it's 5901 port (assuming your tightvnc server is listening on 5901 port) to local 5901 port.

```
ssh -L 5901:127.0.0.1:5901 -C user@192.168.186.111
```

And, on a different terminal connect to the forwarded port for viewing X11:

```
vncviewer localhost:5901
```

Now, when you run a command that's giving you error that's because your DISPLAY variable is not set. You can set it by typing `export DISPLAY=:N` on your `ssh` terminal. Note: The **N** is usually 1, but to verify you can open a terminal in your x11-vnc window and type `echo $DISPLAY`, **N** is whatever value is displayed here.